# struts2 NoSuchMethodException when trying to access Action method from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url, struts2

Struts2 newbie here. I've got a JSP file that has an anchor linking to an Action called "authenticate". When I click on the anchor, I get an error message: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: mypackage.DisplayStuff.authenticate()
    java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)`

Here is my struts.xml

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="display" method="authenticate"
        class="mypackage.DisplayStuff">
        <result name="error">Boo.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">Yay.jsp</result>

    </action>
</package>
```

And here is my action file:

```
package mypackage;

public class DisplayStuff {           
    public String authenticate() {
        return "success";
    }

}
```

And finally, in my JSP, I have this anchor:

```
<a href="<s:url action="display"/>">click here</a>
```

The interesting part, is if I rename my method to the default "execute" I don't get this error. Shouldn't I be able to call any method in my `DisplayStuff` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be

```
<a href="<s:url action="display" method="authenticate"/>">click here</a>
```

Comment: Good eye! That seems to have fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: There's also `namespace` attribute likely to set.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities.

That the error message references a different package my first guess is that you haven't deployed the latest version of your code: `struts.DisplayStuff.authenticate` isn't how it's configured.

Second guess is an issue with a Struts 2 plugin (like "convention") mucking with your  configuration.

Without more details, however, it's difficult to think much more about it.

Comment: Sorry, my package is actually called "struts", I just renamed it to "mypackage" in this question to avoid confusion. I had just forgotten to edit the error message to reflect the change. I've fixed my question.